# Button text not changing after ajax success changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change button text on button click before sending an AJAX request. The text is not changing until *after* the AJAX `success` has run. Why is this happening?

I also tried using the `trigger` and `change` functions.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#contactbutton").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text('Submitting....');
    $('#contactbutton').prop('disabled', true);
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name;
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "emailsend.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        window.open("thankyou.php");
      },
      async: false
    });
    
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: It's because you're using `async: false`. It blocks the browsers rendering thread (amongst others) from doing any work until the AJAX call completes. It's for this reason synchronous requests are incredibly bad practice and should always avoided. Make an async request and your problem goes away